# Owl-carousel function stop working after using splice function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, owl-carousel

I am creating a personal website where I am using owl-carousel lib. for scrollable and draggable images.
my index.html code is:

```
<side-scroll ng-controller="imgListCtrl"></side-scroll>
```

my controller.js is:

```
 App.controller('imgListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
          function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('json-file/my_pic.json').success(function(data) {
                $scope.profile = data;
                var profile= $scope.profile
                Object.size = function(obj) {
                    var size = 0, key;
                    for (key in obj) {
                        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                            size++;
                    }
                    return size;
                    console.log(size);
                };

        // Get the size of an object
                var totalNumberOfProfile = Object.size(profile);
                console.log(totalNumberOfProfile);
                $scope.totalNumberOfProfile= totalNumberOfProfile;
                $scope.categoryOfProfile="Remaining Pictures ";


                 $scope.remove = function(index){
                     $scope.totalNumberOfProfile--;
                     profile.splice(index,1);
                 };

                 $scope.updatedProfile= profile;


          });
        }]);


    App.directive("owlCarousel", function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: false,
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
                  // provide any default options you want
                    var defaultOptions = {
                    };
                    var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                    // combine the two options objects
                    for(var key in customOptions) {
                        defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                    }
                    // init carousel
                    $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
                };
            }
        };
    })

    App.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
        return {

            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: false,
            link: function(scope, element) {
              // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
                if(scope.$last) {
                    scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
                }
            }
        };
    }]);

App.directive('sideScroll', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

    templateUrl: 'side_scroll.html'

    }; 


});
```

my side_scroll.html is:

```
    <div class="discover_hd">{{categoryOfProfile}} <span>({{totalNumberOfProfile}})</span></div>
        <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{ pagination: false, items : 6, itemsDesktopSmall : [760,2.5],
itemsTablet: [490,2] ,itemsMobile : [400,1.7], itemsDesktop : [1200,3.5]}">
            <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="profile in updatedProfile track by $index" >

      <!-- Panel in owl carousel -->


      <li>
      <div class="thumbnail_photo">
          <button class="close" ng-click="remove($index)">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
         </button>
                <a href="#/home/{{profile.id}} " target="_blank"><span class="discover_pic_container" style="background:url({{profile.imageUrl}}) no-repeat left top;background-size:188px 233px;"></span></a>
                <div class="discover_transparent">
                    <div class="discover_name">{{profile.name}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="connect_btn btn-lg"  ng-click="remove()">Connect</button>
      </li>
    </div>          

</data-owl-carousel>
```

while clicking on connect or "x" button owl-carousel function got distorted and it stop working.

please give me any solution